# Java override non abstract method as abstract in extended class

Tags: java, overriding, abstract

So I have a non-abstract method onStop inside the base class.
Is it acceptable to make it abstract in the extented MyTask? The aim is to force the onStop to be implemented by classes that extend the MyTask.

```
public abstract class Task {

    public void onStop() {
    
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public abstract class MyTask extends Task {
    //..

    // Is this acceptable?
    public abstract void onStop();
}
```

Comment: If `MyTask` were *abstract*, then yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable"? If you're wondering if the above will compile then the answer is yes (at least now that you've made `MyTask` abstract), but you could have _easily_ figured that out yourself by trying it.

Comment: @Slaw As in acceptable I mean if this is a good practice?

Comment: I've personally never seen it done, but that doesn't mean much in and of itself. I don't see anything wrong with it though (except maybe a small violation of least surprise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's allowed to do that if `MyTask` is also `abstract`. It forces all the concrete sub-classes of `MyTask` to supply their own implementation of `onStop()` instead of using the `onStop()` implementation of the base `Task` class.